# The constraint cannot be put on properties or getters

Tags: php, validation, constraints, symfony

I try create [custom constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) in symfony 3

I have error

***The constraint App\Bundle\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\Code cannot be put on properties or getters***

```
<?php
// vendor/app/mybundle/Validator/Constraints/Code.php

namespace App\Bundle\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;


class Code extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Error validate message!!!';
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'alias_name';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
      //return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT; // error "The constraint cannot be put on properties or getters"
      return array(self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT, self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT); // working, but $value is a STRING!!!
    }
 }
```

My *vendor/app/mybundle/Validator/Constraints/CodeValidator.php*

```
<?php
// vendor/app/mybundle/Validator/Constraints/CodeValidator.php

namespace App\Bundle\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CodeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
     public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
     {
         $value->getId(); // this code not working, because $value is STRING!!
         $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
             ->atPath('code')
             ->addViolation();
     }
```

}

**where I made a mistake?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to add this to your Constraint :

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"PROPERTY", "METHOD", "ANNOTATION"})
 */
```

**EDIT**

This morning, I took time to try your implementation on a fresh symfony 3 installation.

Also, if you add the `@AcmeAssert\Code` on a property like the following :

```
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as AcmeAssert;

// ...

/**
 * @var string
 * @AcmeAssert\Code
 * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string")
 */
private $code;
```

Only the field will be validated, so `$value` represents the field value of the property.
For example, if you assign the `@AcmeAssert\Code` on the `$code` property in your entity, when the form is submitted, the `$value` of your validator will represent the field value of your `$code` property).

If you add the `@AcmeAssert\Code` on top of your entity like follows :

```
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as AcmeAssert;

/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @AcmeAssert\Code
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FooRepository")
 */
class Foo
```

Then, the $value will represents your full entity, and you can make all validation you want by using getters.

I have added my test project in a repository, you can use it to see how use the two alternatives : [sf3-constraint-test](https://github.com/chalasr/sf3-constraint-test)

In my example, the entity `AppBundle::Bar` has the constraint on property, and `AppBundle::Foo` has the constraint on the whole entity.

Hopes it's what you need !

**EDIT2**

If you are in yaml mapping, use the following for apply the constraint on your whole entity and access to the full object by `$value` in your constraint :

```
AppBundle\Entity\AcmeEntity:
    constraints:
        - App\Bundle\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\Code: ~
```

On top of your mapping.

And if you want just apply the constraint on one property, and access the value of the field using `$value` , stay how you are and do your logic on `$value` which is a string (value of the field corresponding to the entity property constrained in mapping), it's something like :

```
AppBundle\Entity\AcmeEntity:
    properties:
            # ...
            code:
                - App\Bundle\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\Code: ~
```

Comment: i change my, @chalasr look again. please

Comment: I've made changes to fit to your need.

Comment: thank you very much , which has to help me.I use yml files for mapping and validation. Maybe that's the problem ? Do you think it matters ? be sure to use annotations only?

Comment: I don't think it can cause the problem, try to inspect my code and yours to fine where is the problem. I do not have enough code from you to locate the bug in your code. But the @Annotation on top of your constraint is mandatory. And the mapping format is very personal, I used annotations only for entities, and now I use it in my controllers because of FOSRestBundle, it is in best practices of Symfony.

Answer (score 4):

You created a constraint that should only be applied to an entire entity, such as:

```
/**
 * @AppAssert\SectionCode
 */
class MyEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

If you want your constraint applied to members of a class, remove your `getTargets()` function altogether.

Comment: what about  @AppAssert\SectionCode("propertyName") ?

Comment: @jason-roman

i change getTargets

    public function getTargets()
     {
          return array(self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT, self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT);
     }

but in validate() method $value variable is not object of my Entity, is string

Comment: Are you validating your entire entity, or just a property of your entity?  If the entity, then just keep it as `self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT`, but please post the code where you are trying to apply the constraint, rather than just the constraint and validator.

Comment: The question should be closed because this answer solves your primary problem (which the question is about)

Comment: In version 3.4 of Symfony (haven't checked 4 yet), you would in fact need to override the getTargets() method. If you look in Constraint::getTargets() you'll see it returns `self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT;` by default. Overriding the getTargets() methods and returning `return parent::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;` from it was how I solved this problem.